# c nested scanf in printf along with another variable

Tags: c, function, printf, scanf, variadic-functions

I wrote the following c codes

code1

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int z = 9;
    printf("%d\n", printf("%d%d", scanf("%d", &z), z));
    return 0;
}
```

code2

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int z = 9;
    printf("%d\n", printf("%d%d", z, scanf("%d", &z)));
    return 0;
}
```

for both of them I entered 2 inputs '1' and 'a' to see how the output varies. And here are the results:

| input | code1 | code2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 192 | 112 |
| a | 092 | 902 |

It is said that the evaluation order of arguments in `C` is unspecified, but what is causing this behavior? And I have also tried it with more than 1 variable and all possible orders.

> It appears to me that the evaluation is being right to left. I can be wrong, just want to know how it is being done.

Comment: *It is said that the evaluation order of arguments in C is unspecified, but what is causing this behavior?* - the specific implementation design choices made by the specific C library developers. If you need the exact details - you might be able to find the sources of your C library, assuming it is open-source one.

Comment: It might be clearer if you enter other than 1 since there is another 1 around (the return value from `scanf`).

Comment: @WeatherVane i tried different values like 2 and the output i got for code1 was same and for code2 was 212.

Comment: Don't use `2` either, since that's the value of `printf`. Use distinct values. Then you don't have to figure out which `1` is which or which `2` is which.

Comment: @WeatherVane for that purpose i can just omit out the outer printf

Answer (score 4):

> It is said that the evaluation order of arguments in C is unspecified

That is correct.  They may be evaluated in any order that the implementation chooses.  As such, you shouldn't write code that depends on function arguments being evaluated in any particular order.

While this code exhibits unspecified behavior, it does *not* exhibit undefined behavior.  This is because the evaluation of the argument that calls `scanf` contains a sequence point at the time the function is called (as well as for each statement inside of the function), so `z` is not being read and written without a sequence point.

If you instead did this:

```
int rval = scanf("%d", &z);
printf("%d\n", printf("%d%d", rval, z));
```

It would print the number of items read and the value that was read in (assuming one was in fact read in) for the inner call to `printf`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but i want to know why is this happening is what i want to understand

Comment: Because that's what the implementation wanted to do.  Other implementations might do something different.  This same implementation might do something different if you change optimization settings or even add extra unrelated statements.  The point is that you as a developer need to account for the fact you can't depend on the order.

Comment: this is actually a question a friend of mine got in an coding assignment. I am just trying to help him

Comment: @TusharJain A compiler is fully within its rights to, for example, evaluate left-to-right on weekdays and right-to-left on weekends.  If you really want to know you would need to look at the source code of the specific compiler you're interested in.

Comment: @TusharJain MSVC outputs 112 for both codes (and the same as you for input 'a') But it's clearer if I enter 5, when the output is 152 and 512.